# Image prefix (url rewrite)

Tags: preg-match

I'm use this tutorials to add watermark on my images:
http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/forum/index.php?topic=15067.0

All JPG are correctly marked up with this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^tn].*\.(jpg))$ watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=watermark.png [NC]
```

Now, i need to apply different watermarks based on file prefix, like:

AA-myimage.jpg (apply aa-watermark.png to all files with **AA-** prefix)

BB-myimage.jpg (apply bb-watermark.png to all images with **BB-** prefix)

There is a way to add this on htaccess?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-(.+?\.jpg)$ watermark.php?image=$1-$2&watermark=$1-watermark.png [NC,L]
```

Comment: anubhava, thanks.
But how to define file prefix to apply correct watermark?

Comment: Hmm I didn't get your comment. This rule will pickup prefix which is first 2 letters and pass that in the `watermark` parameter. So for ex:  `AA-myimage.jpg` will be internally rewritten to: `/watermark.php?image=AA-myimage.jpg&watermark=AA-watermark.png [NC,L]`

Comment: It is better to not create duplicate questions for same issue. Address it here.

Comment: As I asked if you can provide what `watermark.php` URI works for you then I can provide you correct answer.

Comment: watermark.php is here: http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/forum/index.php?topic=15067.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41662/discussion-between-user2307958-and-anubhava)